# PyQT5 Python 3.12 gif overlay

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gif, qtimer

There are problems using the QTimer function. In the class initialization after the timer ran, the window is hidden successfuly, but if I try to call it inside the show_window function, the window is not hidden.

```
import sys
import keyboard
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QMovie, QCursor
from PyQt5.Qt import QLabel, QSize

 
class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        cursor_pos = QCursor().pos()
        screen_number = QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(cursor_pos)
        screen_rect = QApplication.desktop().availableGeometry(screen_number)
        w_width = screen_rect.width()
        w_height = screen_rect.height()
        print(w_width, w_height)

        keyboard.on_press(self.show_window)
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.hide)
        self.timer.start(5000)

        self.setWindowTitle('Gif_overlay')
        self.setGeometry(screen_rect.right() - w_height//4, screen_rect.bottom() - w_height//4,
                         w_height//4, w_height//4)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
        # self.setWindowFlags(Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)

        self.label = QLabel(self)
        movie = QMovie("1.gif")
        gif_size = (w_height//4, w_height//4)
        movie.setScaledSize(QSize(*gif_size))
        self.label.resize(*gif_size)
        self.label.setMovie(movie)
        self.label.move(0, 0)
        movie.start()

    def show_window(self, key):
        if not (self.isVisible()):
            self.show()
            self.timer.start(5000)
        else:
            self.timer.setInterval(5000) 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Example()
    w.show()
    #w.hide()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I use python 3.12, the library version below

```
Package            Version
------------------ ----------
certifi            2023.11.17
charset-normalizer 3.3.2
colorama           0.4.6
decorator          4.4.2
idna               3.6
imageio            2.33.0
imageio-ffmpeg     0.4.9
keyboard           0.13.5
moviepy            1.0.3
numpy              1.26.2
Pillow             9.5.0
pip                23.2.1
proglog            0.1.10
pygame             2.5.2
PyQt5              5.15.10
PyQt5-Qt5          5.15.2
PyQt5-sip          12.13.0
requests           2.31.0
setuptools         69.0.2
tqdm               4.66.1
urllib3            2.1.0
```

I want to put the gif on the screen when the user types on the keyboard and a minute after the stop, even outside the app window.

Comment: Try to run the program in a terminal or prompt, it will probably show you some warning about QTimer not being able to be started from a different thread. Try to create a dummy signal for the class, use `on_press(self.someSignal.emit)` and connect that signal to `show_window`.